# Creating a jar file

Tags: java, jar

I have to create a jar file. I'm a beginner. I created a manifest file as forjar.txt which contains,

`Main-Class: gmain`

where gmain is my java file name. In command prompt, I compiled it and typed the following command.

jar cfm v.jar forjar.txt gmain.class

It created a jar file. But, while I run it, nothing happens. While I compile, nearly 25 classes get created, because my file includes many classes within it. So, should I include that too while creating jar file? Or is there any simple way such that including the entire contents of a particular folder. My folder contains images too that are needed by the program. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Have you organized your classes in packages?

Comment: try netbean it will give facility to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***So, should I include that too while creating jar file?***

Yes, all files need to be included. Try

```
jar cfm v.jar forjar.txt *
```

Comment: does that * indicate all the files in the folder?i mean, classes and images?

Comment: Yup. And it the jar command works recursively too, so it should include all directories.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. it worked now. I have another doubt, Sir. Actually I need to run this jar file in another laptop. Do I need java installed there, Sir? Should I set path there too?

Comment: Also, is it enough that I take this file alone? Or I need to take the entire folder? Will it work if I store it in desktop, my folder will be in another location. kindly tell me, Sir.

Comment: If you include all files needed to execute your program in the jar, then it should be sufficient to just copy the .jar-file to the other computer. Keep in mind that if you depend on other .jar files such as libraries etc you either have to copy these too, or include them in your jar. There are plenty of questions and answers on that topic here on stackoverflow, so I won't elaborate on that here.